# Building custom OBS Studio build versions

Tags: cmake, obs-studio

I'm trying to edit the source code of OBS Studio and make my own build from it. I have succeeded in building the OBS Studio, when the source code is cloned from the GitHub repository and no changes have been made. However, if I try to make my own changes to the code and build it with CMake, I get the following error:

`Error in configuration process, project files may be invalid`

EDIT: here is the full error:

```
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0 to target Windows 10.0.19042.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:62 (include):
include could not find load file:

ObsHelpers


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:63 (include):
include could not find load file:

ObsCpack


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:87 (string):
string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:91 (list):
list index: 1 out of range (-1, 0)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:92 (list):
list index: 2 out of range (-1, 0)


CMake Error: File 
C:/Users/Miika/Desktop/VSCode/PROJECTS/obs_mini/UI/obs.rc.in does not exist.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:98 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file


CMake Error: File 
C:/Users/Miika/Desktop/VSCode/PROJECTS/obs_mini/cmake/winrc/obs-module.rc.in 
does not exist.
CMake Error at deps/w32-pthreads/CMakeLists.txt:8 (configure_file):
configure_file Problem configuring file


CMake Error at deps/w32-pthreads/CMakeLists.txt:30 (install_obs_core):
Unknown CMake command "install_obs_core".


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

How can I fix this? Does this have something to do with the CMakeLists files?

Comment: Please, show the **actual** error message, which is somewhere **above** the line `Error in configuration process, project files may be invalid`.

Comment: The full error is now in the question @Tsyvarev

Comment: "include could not find load file" - It seems your change of `CMakeLists.txt` was wrong. But since you don't specify what you have actually changed, we could only guess.

Comment: Well, I haven't made any changes to any of the CMakeLists.txt files, so I'm guessing that might be the issue.

Comment: Btw, there are like 20 different CMakeLists.txt files in the subfolders. Do I have to make changes to all of them or is there on "master" file that is only required to be edited when making changes to the code? @Tsyvarev

Comment: I don't understand what do you want from us (Stack Overflow). You say that everything works in unmodified version of OBS Studio sources. You modified them, and got errors. You ask us how to fix these errors, but we don't see your modifications causing them. How could we help?

Comment: **Unmodified** `CMakeLists.txt:62` [refers](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L62) to the line `include(ObsHelpers)`. On correct execution, this line should include a file `cmake/Modules/ObsHelpers.cmake`, which [exists](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/blob/master/cmake/Modules/ObsHelpers.cmake) in unmodified version of the sources. Make sure that you still have this file after your modifications.